# Call a method on all classes that implements that method

Tags: java, interface

I have an Activity and 10 fragments. I've created an interface and implement it on all Fragments. How can I call that method on all Fragments from the Activity?

```
  public interface OnConnectListener {
      void isDeviceConnected(boolean b);
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

Using your suggestions I did this:

```
public void isDeviceConnected(boolean b, List fragmentList) {
    for (OnConnectListener listener : getOnConnectListeners(fragmentList)) {
        listener.isDeviceConnected(b);
    }
}

public List<OnConnectListener> getOnConnectListeners(List fragmentList) {
    List<OnConnectListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object o : fragmentList) {
        if (o instanceof OnConnectListener) {
            listeners.add((OnConnectListener) o);
        }
    }
    return listeners;
}
```

Now I just use:

```
isDeviceConnected(true, fragmentList);
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: mark an answer as correct please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your "Activity" class holds a reference of 10  "onConnectListener" instances, you can loop thru each and call isDeviceConnected like so:

```
private List<onConnectListener> onConnectListeners;
....
for(onConnectListener onConnectListener: onConnectListeners) {
    onConnectListener.isDeviceConnected(true); // or false
}
```

By the way: Java naming conventions state that class names start with capital letters, and iterfaces usually start with the letter "I"
So its best if you name your interface `IOnConnectListener`

Answer (score 0):

This is perfect case for Observer pattern

http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html

Comment: Can't you please give an example?